# Array of numbers, how many solutions/ways?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

Let's say, we have an array/matrix $n \times m$ and we need to find, how many ways can we fill this array with numbers from $\{ 1, \ldots , m\cdot n \}$, but:

1) every number can be used only 1 time

2) every column and every row should be sorted in increasing order

For example, if we have $n = m = 3$, there are 42 different ways to do this.

I was thinking about this problem, but I can't find out any *simple* formula to compute this for every $n, m$.

We can solve this problem by writnig a program that uses backtracking method/algorithm [1] but it has huge complexity and problem is solved by computer, and I want to know, how to do this *by hand*.

Sombody told me, that in this problem I can use some kind of Catalan numbers [2] [3], but I'm not sure about this method.

So, what do You think about this problem and its solution?

[1] Backtracking (Wikipedia): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking 
[2] Catalan numbers (Wikipedia): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number 
[3] Catalan numbers (OEIS): http://oeis.org/A000108

Answer (score 6):

These are Young tableaux.  OEIS has the numbers.  For the square case, see [A039622](http://oeis.org/A039622).   For the rectangular case, see [A060854](http://oeis.org/A060854)

Answer (score 5):

You are counting the number of [standard Young tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) of shape $(m, m, m, ...)$ (where $m$ occurs $n$ times).  The formula that counts these is called the [hook length formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Dimension_of_a_representation).  It correctly reproduces the answer

$$\frac{9!}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2} = 42$$

for the example you gave.  The general formula seems annoying to write down.  In the special case $n = 2$ you get Catalan numbers; this is a nice exercise and it is worth trying to prove this with and then without the hook length formula.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way, to compute this in faster way?

Comment: @guram: you can probably deduce a recursive formula, either from the hook-length formula or directly.  But I don't know what you mean by "faster way."  For small values of m, n these formulas work quite nicely, and for large m, n the problem is just hard; it is just hard to compute factorials exactly.  Do you want an asymptotic formula?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: as You wrote: "it is just hard to compute factorials exactly". Is there a way to avoid computing factorials by using other formula? And, what do You mean by "small values"?

Comment: @guram: I don't know, but my guess is no.  By small values I meant, say, single-digit (really small).  You asked for a method that works by hand; this is such a method.  That's all.  If what you actually want is something else, you should say so.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Now I am interested in fast algorithm to solve this problem. I know it's possible with backtracking method, but I'm not sure, how to do this. Or is there another method to find the answer.

Comment: OK, I think, that the best optimization I can do is preprocessing, because either backtracking method takes long time to find solution for _big_ $m, n$ or computation directly from the formula requires a lot of big-numbers calculations (factorials).